# Looping through grouped and assign value in new column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to create a new column and assign value for each group (in this case is Color), and in each group:

if Function column is View and Access column is no, the value for the new column will be 'No' for this group;

if Function column = View and Access column = yes, the value for new column will be same as 'Access' for the rows of the group

**Data:**

| Type | Color | Function | Access |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Blue | Add | yes |
| A | Blue | View | no |
| A | Red | Add | no |
| A | Red | View | yes |
| B | Blue | Add | yes |
| B | Blue | View | no |

**Desired Outcome:**

| Type | Color | Function | Access | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Blue | Add | yes | no |
| A | Blue | View | no | no |
| A | Red | Add | no | no |
| A | Red | View | yes | yes |
| B | Blue | Add | yes | no |
| B | Blue | View | no | no |

```
# I created a new column first before grouping them
data['New Column'] = ''
data_grouped = data.groupby(['Type', 'Color']

# attempted to loop but stuck here #
for group_name, df_group in data_grouped:
    print(format(group_name))

    for row_index, row in df_group.iterrows():

        if (row['Function'] == 'View') & (row['Access'] == 'no'):
            row['New Column'] = 'no'

        print(col, column_type)
```

Comment: What happens when `df['Function'] == 'Add`?

Comment: Hi, if it is df['Function'] == 'Add', it doesn't matter. As long as it is df['Function'] == 'View' and df['Access'] == 'No', the rows for that grouping should be df['New Column'] == 'No'. If df['Function'] == 'View' and df['Access'] == 'Yes', then for each row in that grouping, the new column should be the value from df['Access']. Hope this is clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want a 'no' for all other cases (except from the pair View-Yes), you can do the following:

```
data['New Column'] = np.where((data['Function']=='View') & (data['Access']=='yes'), 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but if data['Function']=='View') & (data['Access']=='yes', data['New Column'] should follow the value from data['Access']. It can be value 'No' if data['Function']=='Add' and access = no for the same group of data['Function']=='View') & (data['Access']=='yes'